# Arch, Ubuntu: So what's the deal with libudev.so.0?

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, libraries, udev, chrome

I'm interested in building Linux desktop apps with Web front-end technologies. Both platforms I've tried -- [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)/[CEFPython](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/), and [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/), seem to have a dependency on `libudev.so.0`, and fail in a most unpleasant manner when they don't find it.

`libudev.so.0`, however, doesn't seem to be provided by any package in recent Ubuntu releases, and this [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libudev.so.0/) only implements the common, yet controversial fix of symlinking it to `libudev.so.1`. On the other hand, the Chromium browser, on a recent version of which both CEF and Awesomium are based, runs happily without that dependency.

Does anyone know what's the story behind this library? And how do I properly ensure reliable operation across different Linux distros for software that relies on embedding Chromium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `udev` was brought into the whole `systemd` revolution, and became part of a larger, more complex system. Various changes incremented the interface, and required a jump from `.so.0` to `.so.1`.

Rather than supporting both the old interface and the new interface by providing both `.so.0` and `.so.1`, the developers opted to say "fuck it, we'll make them all upgrade their dependencies!" and they dropped `.so.0` from the binary package.

It's possible to build an older version of `libudev` that still provides `.so.0` if it's necessary.

It's also possible that this change is recent enough that most package maintainers haven't caught the glitch to explicitly state "this package requires `libudev` before version `xyz`" and most developers haven't switched their binaries to require the latest version of `libudev`.

And a third possibility is that some key developers actually symlinked `.so.0` to `.so.1`.

Basically the same mess of possibilities that happens when any key component makes a major interface change.

Source: [Wikipedia on udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)

And: [Program Library HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

Comment: What bothers me is this: *"When a new version of a library is binary-incompatible with the old one the soname needs to change"* If `libudev.so.1` is binary incompatible with `libudev.so.0`, why does the symlinking hack work? And how reliable is it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in Chromium tracker to remove runtime dependency on `libudev.so.0`. It includes some useful information as well, [see this link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415212).

Google Chrome installer creates symlink when needed, [see this link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/installer/linux/common/symlinks.include&l=27).